# Image Size notification android

Tags: java, android, image

I would like to know which size do I need the image in the notification. If I put the ic_launcher 96x96 is that you see cut I would like that you could see in full, normally ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find icon size information here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification.

Comment: This link now redirects to material.io which doesn't include sizes of the notification icons.

Answer (score 1):

**Android supports both Small and Large Notification Icons.**

**Small Notification Icons** - by default our SDK automatically uses either a white bell icon or your App's launcher icon. Starting with Android 5, the OS forces Small Notification Icons to be all white when your app targets Android API 21+. If you don't make a correct icon, it will most likely be displayed as a bell or solid white icon in the status bar.

**Large Notification Icons** - The large notification icon will show up to the left of the notification text on Android 4.0.3 - 6.0 devices, and shows on the right for Android 7.0+ devices. If you do not set a large icon, the small icon will be used instead. OneSignal will auto scale large notification icons for you to prevent the icon from being cropped.

**Small Icon**
If you prefer to create your own icons, you must make your icons the following size and colors:

Type    Size (px)
Small Notification Icon (mdpi)

24x24

Small Notification Icon (hdpi)

36x36

Small Notification Icon (xhdpi)

48x48

Small Notification Icon (xxhdpi)

72x72

Small Notification Icon (xxxhdpi)

96x96

**Other - Large Icon**
Type    Size (px)
Large Notification Icon (xxxhdpi)

256x256

Answer (score 1):

**Notification icon size in Android**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the icon is white and at least 24 x 24